# R Sample By Minimum Cell Size

Tags: r, data.table, sample

```
set.seed(1)
data=data.frame(SCHOOL = rep(1:10, each = 1000), GRADE = sample(7:12, r = T, size = 10000),SCORE = sample(1:100, r = T, size = 10000))
```

I have 'data' that contains information about student test score. I wish to: count how many GRADE for each SCHOOL, and then take the smallest value of GRADE for all SCHOOLS. Like this:

For each SCHOOL count the number of rows for a specific GRADE.
Then for each GRADE find the smallest values across all SCHOOLs.
Finally I wish to take a random sample based on the smallest value found in step 2.

So basically in this basic example with two SCHOOLs and GRADE 7 and GRADE 8:
[image]

SCHOOL 1 has 2 SCOREs for GRADE 7 and SCHOOL 1 has 3 SCOREs for GRADE 8.

SCHOOL 2 has 1 SCOREs for GRADE 7 and SCHOOL 2 has 4 SCOREs for GRADE 8.

So the new data contains one SCORE for GRADE 7 from SCHOOL 1 and SCHOOL 2, and three SCORE for GRADE 8 from SCHOOL 1 and SCHOOL 2 and these SCORE that are picked are RANDOMLY SAMPLED.

like this:

[image]

My attempt:
data[, .SD[sample(x = .N, size = min(sum(GRADE), .N))], by = .(SCHOOL,GRADE]

Comment: @akrun do you have suggestions and thoughts?

Comment: @Valentin do you have suggestions and thoughts maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows your description of how to do it step-by-step.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(data)
data[, N := .N, .(SCHOOL, GRADE)]
data[, N := min(N), GRADE]
data[, .(SCORE = sample(SCORE, N)), .(SCHOOL, GRADE, N)][, -'N']
```

If you have multiple `SCORE`-like columns and you want keep the same rows from each then you can use `.SD` like in your attempt:

```
data[, .SD[sample(.N, N)], .(SCHOOL, GRADE, N)][, -'N']
```

Comment: Thank you do you mind actually just explaining your last row it IS PERFECT!

Comment: It splits the rows by `SCHOOL` and `GRADE` and then runs the sample function once for each combination of them taking `N` (which we just worked out) of the `SCORE`s. Then `data.table` magically pieces the table back together for us. `[, -'N']` is just deleting that column, you can remove that bit to see what is there.

Comment: that is perfect thank you so much i have just one another question. what if i have a bunch of other variables like SCORE but I wish to do the same exact thing which is just select the rows as we do it. Is it possible to do this for the whole data frame and not just 'SCORE' ?

Comment: I added a line in the answer to do it that way instead.